# WebView in javaFX, not work with Whatsapp web

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need to access the WhatsApp Web from a JavaFX application I'm not getting. When the page opens I get a message to use another browser. I have tried to change the UserAgent but it does not work.

[image]

Code:

```
WebEngine eng = webView.getEngine();
eng.load("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
eng.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
eng.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you check my answer? I'd love to hear your feedback!

Answer (score 5):

I was unable to access whatsapp from JavaFX, it does not seem to be an user-agent issue, but rather either some dependency is missing when using FX, or just whatsapp is blocking using some other metric, but found an alternative; [Pandomium](https://github.com/dzikoysk/Pandomium)

It is not compatible well with JavaFX, but works well with Swing, and can access to any site without thinking about user-agent, or any dependency issue since it is a [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef) implementation, that is Chromium Framework for Java, essentially embedded Chrome for Java.

Just doing the following with Pandomium jar in your dependency does the trick;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PandomiumSettings settings = PandomiumSettings.getDefaultSettingsBuilder().build();
    settings.getCefSettings().cache_path = "C:\\temp\\cache";
    // setting this option is paramount otherwise no cache is kept, and sesions are lost

    Pandomium pandomium = new Pandomium(settings);
    pandomium.initialize();

    PandomiumClient client = pandomium.createClient();
    PandomiumBrowser browser = client.loadURL("https://web.whatsapp.com");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(browser.toAWTComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setTitle("Whatsapp");
    frame.setSize(1720, 840);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal yeah, I already mentioned that in my answer, but Pandomium is more accessible with maven as well, in case that is needed

Comment: I tried whatsapp web using JCEF. It worked but each time I launched the app, I was required to scan the QR code and relogin.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal you'd have that issue with JavaFX as well if it worked at all, I think to have that you'd need some cookie management, still this way you can access the website as the original question requires. I will investigate further & test.

Comment: As an alternative for Android webview, I used crosswalk-project which is again chromium embedded in Android. Crosswalk doesn't seem to have that problem. Once you login to whatsapp in crosswalk's webview, you stay logged in even when the app is closed and relaunched.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal ah, it was so simple, I was able to make re-log unnecessary. All you need to set is `cache_path`, let me update the answer, I did not need to relog and my whatsapp session was stored within local cache. Should be similar in JCEF as well, the [answer](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=15086) I found was for it.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal were you able to confirm this solution with the caching?

Comment: Yes. But I wanted to know what feature is missing in JavaFX webview that keeps us from accessing whatsapp web.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal I tried to pinpoint this as well, but couldn't. Either some dependency from whatsapp (e.g. some js dependency) is not supported, or some basic browser features that are not detected. You can check the differences [here](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013137-jxbrowser-vs-javafx-webview), since `JxBrowser` is a JCEF with JavaFX webview product, but paid  Since we do not know either whatsapp or jxbrowser source code, it is tough to detect the exact reason.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal you can theoretically take off features one by one from JCEF/Pandomium until you get the same screen as webview, that would be a way to reverse engineer the issue, but I think there is no need since it is only whatsapp based logic, and might change tomorrow, since what they define in their end is always changing, better to utilize chromium, a proper embedded browser to evade such current & future issues IMO

Answer (score 3):

The following simple WebViewTest class can help you determine the issue (or at least get closer to determining it):

```
package test;

import com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebConsoleListener;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        // create WebView
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.setFontScale(1.20);
        webView.setZoom(1.20);

        // print debug info
        WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener(
                (webView1, message, lineNumber, sourceId) ->
                        System.out.println("Console: [" + sourceId + ":" + lineNumber + "] " + message));

        // create WebEngine
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webEngine.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36");

        webEngine.load("https://web.whatsapp.com/");

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The console output when running the above code on my machine is the following:

```
Console: [https://web.whatsapp.com/vendor2.3973e7c149ced441846f.js:11] Unhandled rejection: https://web.whatsapp.com/vendor2.3973e7c149ced441846f.js:12:20732
Y@https://web.whatsapp.com/vendor2.3973e7c149ced441846f.js:11:7487
G@https://web.whatsapp.com/vendor2.3973e7c149ced441846f.js:11:7307
getDatabaseNames@https://web.whatsapp.com/vendor2.3973e7c149ced441846f.js:12:20699
deleteLegacyDBs@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:16:16530
i@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:16:14199
"cceejgejjg"@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:16:16681
a@https://web.whatsapp.com/progress.05fda25452b93c319bddcb3c2f6fdcb3.js:2:111
"hcddbeaic"@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:15:10748
a@https://web.whatsapp.com/progress.05fda25452b93c319bddcb3c2f6fdcb3.js:2:111
"baggieehcg"@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:22:22662
a@https://web.whatsapp.com/progress.05fda25452b93c319bddcb3c2f6fdcb3.js:2:111
"jfefjijii"@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:9:25328
a@https://web.whatsapp.com/progress.05fda25452b93c319bddcb3c2f6fdcb3.js:2:111
i@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:10:30397
d@https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:6:11780
r@https://web.whatsapp.com/progress.05fda25452b93c319bddcb3c2f6fdcb3.js:2:5338
onload@https://web.whatsapp.com/progress.05fda25452b93c319bddcb3c2f6fdcb3.js:2:4883
Console: [https://web.whatsapp.com/app.cf6d46b7e29e2f232d65.js:3] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://web.whatsapp.com/img/c5088e888c97ad440a61d247596f88e5.png due to access control checks.
```

The part that says `Unhandled rejection: https://web.whatsapp.com/vendor2.3973e7c149ced441846f.js:12:20732` points to a (pretty unreadable) JavaScript file on the page you are trying to load.

My JavaScript is not very strong, but from what I can tell from a quick look, the page seems to require IndexedDB support, which is not available (to the best of my knowledge) in JavaFX WebView.